# not getting expected data using query expressions on datatable c#

Tags: c#, linq, datatable

I want to create a sorted list of users that appear in one datatable “StatsTable”.

I need to get the userID from StatsTable and then use this to find the UserName in another datatable “UserTable”. When I have these I want to make the userID the Key and the UserName the Value in the sorted list.

I managed to get the userID and add it to the sorted list but the userName is coming through as “System.Data.EnumerableRowCollection`1[System.String]”.

What am I doing wrong? Thanks for your help.

```
    SortedList UserList = new SortedList();

    List<double> listofUserIDs = StatsTable.AsEnumerable()
    .Select(uid => uid.Field<double>("UserID")).ToList<double>();
    foreach (double UID in listofUserIDs)
    {
        string userName = UserTable.AsEnumerable()
            .Where(id => double.Equals(id.Field<double>("UserID"), UID))
        .Select(name => name.Field<string>("First_Name") + " " + name.Field<string>("Last_Name")).ToString();

         UserList[UID] = userName;
    }
```

Comment: Why are you using a `double` as an ID? That's a *really* bad idea in general.

Comment: Not my idea, im using a database that already exists. Besides that does not answer the question.

Comment: No, that's why it's a comment rather than an answer. You'll see a fuller answer from me elsewhere on the page. But you should take action ASAP to fix this. It *will* bite you sooner or later.

Comment: Thanks, I do apprectiate the help. I definitley see the point, but there is nothing I can do about it right now, I just have to work with what I've got.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You should use `Enumerable.Join` to link both tables and select what you need. In this case i would use a `Tuple<int, string>` whereas the `int` is the UserID(a UserID with decimal places makes no sense, does it?) and the string is the username:

```
var query = from rStats in StatsTable.AsEnumerable()
            join rUser in UserTable.AsEnumerable()
            on rStats.Field<int>("UserID") equals rUser.Field<int>("UserID")
            select new {
                UserID   = rStats.Field<int>("UserID"), 
                UserName = string.Format("{0} {1}"
                               , rUser.Field<string>("First_Name")
                               , rUser.Field<string>("Last_Name"))
            };

List<Tuple<int, string>> users = query
    .OrderBy(u => u.UserName)
    .Select(u => Tuple.Create(u.UserID, u.UserName))
    .ToList();
```

You can access a tuple via the `Item` properties:

```
foreach(var user in users)
    Console.WriteLine("UserID:{0} UserName:{1}",user.Item1,user.Item2);
```

Comment: Tim, can you please explain to me what a Tuple is? It works fine but I have never heard of it before. What is it used for?

Comment: @DavidMuller: you can understand a [`Tuple<T>`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.tuple.aspx) as a simple "class-on-the-fly". It enables to _materialize_ things without needing to create a real class with these properties. But it also has properties `Item1`,`Item2`,`ItemX` and so on which are not really meaningful. So you should use them just with few properties.

Answer (score 4):

Firstly, I would avoid using `double` for anything requiring equality. Strings, GUIDs, and integers are all fine for IDs - doubles, not so much.

Secondly, I'd do all of this as a join in LINQ - you really don't need to iterate over every single items each time. You're turning an O(N+M) operation into an O(N + M * N) operation.

Thirdly, the reason your query isn't working is that you're simply projecting to a *sequence* of strings. You may happen to know that there will be exactly one match, but you need to tell the computer that. Calling `ToString()` on a sequence isn't going to give you anything useful. For example, you could use `Single()` or `SingleOrDefault()`:

```
string userName = UserTable.AsEnumerable()
    .Where(id => double.Equals(id.Field<double>("UserID"), UID))
    .Select(name => name.Field<string>("First_Name") + " "
                  + name.Field<string>("Last_Name"))
    .Single();
```

Once you're using `Single()` (or any of the other calls which return a single value) you don't need `ToString()` at all, as the result will already be a string.

Using `Single()`, an exception will be thrown if there isn't exactly one result. Using `SingleOrDefault()`, an exception will still be thrown if there are multiple results, but you'll just get a `null` reference if there are no results. If it would be an error for there to be anything other than a single result, you should use `Single()`.

Answer (score 2):

This is because you are using the `.AsEnumerable()` which returns the source of type which returns usually a list. You can return this as a list using `.ToList<string>(`) and select the first record or you can use `FirstOrDefault()`; instead of `.ToList<string>()` to return the first record.

Answer (score 1):

The code should appere as this:

```
SortedList UserList = new SortedList();

List<double> listofUserIDs = StatsTable.AsEnumerable()
.Select(uid => uid.Field<double>("UserID")).ToList<double>();
foreach (double UID in listofUserIDs)
{
    string userName = UserTable.AsEnumerable()
        .Where(id => double.Equals(id.Field<double>("UserID"), UID))
    .Select(name => name.Field<string>("First_Name") + " " + name.Field<string>("Last_Name")).FirstOrDefault().ToString();

     UserList[UID] = userName;
}
```

You should add `FirstOrDefault()` before `ToString()`, because, select will give you a new enumerable, and not a single object!.

Comment: Calling `ToString()` on the result of `FirstOrDefault()` is a bad idea. The result will *already* be a string reference - but if `FirstOrDefault()` returns null, you'll end up with a `NullReferenceException`.

Comment: It is a very preliminary solution, he should work on it, but thank you Jon!